# How to solve problem with ssh authentication?

Tags: ssh

I am trying to login into remote server without password using ssh but I am get the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

To copy .pub key to the server, I had:

```
PasswordAuthentication = yes (in the sshd_config file).
```

After I copied the .pub key, the i disabled the password in the ssh_config I had:

```
PasswordAuthentication = no
```

Now when I tried to ssh:

ssh 'server@192.168.xx.x'

I was getting the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

How can I solve the problem?

I have changed the authorized_keys permission, the .ssh/ permission and so on, but the problem persist. I have even used the ssh-agent $SHELL && ssh-add command.

Comment: What are the current permissions on the `.ssh` directory and the files therein on the `server` system?

Comment: `authorized_keys` in remote host must be 644

Comment: using `ssh -vvv` will give more verbose output - but is the .pub key in the your authorized_keys file on the server you want to access?

Comment: How do you pass your private key? Using ssh-agent or ssh -i ?

Comment: @Panki They say they start a shell through the agent and then add the key with `ssh-add`.

Comment: If you have access to change `sshd_config`, you should also have access to read the server-side logs. When `sshd` rejects a connection, it will log the rejection reason on the server side, but **won't necessarily reveal the reason to the client** which is unauthenticated and so must be assumed to be possibly hostile at that point. If the client is legitimate, they can contact the server admin and get troubleshooting information that way.

Answer (score 0):

I always use below step to create new ssh connection to remote machines:

1. Generate a new `ssh` key pair (just press enter until back to shell):

   ```
   localhost$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
   localhost$ cp .ssh/id_rsa.pub .ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
2. Copying the newly created public key to remote machine:

   ```
   localhost$ ssh-copy-id username@myIP
   username@myIP password:
   ```
3. Now try to login (there will be no password prompt):

   ```
   ssh username@myIP
   ```

> Notes:  I never edit `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` so maybe you can
>   restore them back to the original state unless they already connected.